# How to modifies the Xml tag using Java and insert new tag inside the Xml File?

Tags: java, xml

I need to add following method tag in the given below Xml File using Java.

```
<method id="img_8497" img_src="/media/media/12508/23804/AWH13.ThreeKids.SM.jpg" img_height="180" img_width="317" title_="playing^kids"/>
```

In this tag it have 5 attributes and in java i can given it as local variable. In the Xml creation i need to use the 5  attributes. The method tag will be child tag for LiberaryBook
and In option it may be child of Liberary tag too. I need to insert the method tag between LiberayBook and Liberary tag. If the number of Liberay tag may less or increase. dipend on that it should create method for Liberay tag.(FOR loop).

```
<parent>

<Body class="student" id="181_student_method_3">

<Book class="Book_In_School_11" id="181_student_method_11"/>

<subject class="subject_information " id="181_student_subject_12"/>

<div class="div_passage " id="181_div_method_3">

<p class=" paragraph_book_name" id="181_paragraph_13">

<LiberaryBook class="Liberary" id="181_Liberary_9" >

<Liberary class="choice "     Uninversity="University_Liberary_1">Dubliners</Liberary>

<Liberary class="choice "  Uninversity="University_Liberary_2">Adventure if sherlock Holmes</Liberary>

<Liberary class="choice "  Uninversity="University_Liberary_3">Charlotte’s Web</Liberary>

<Liberary class="choice " Uninversity="University_Liberary_4">The   Outsiders</Liberary>

</LiberaryBook>

</p>

</div>

</Body>

</parent>
```

Comment: Have you looked into JAXB?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Schema for your file (use XSD/XML Schema Generator)
2. Insert XSD file to your project
3. Run IntelliJ IDEA context menu of your XSD file --> Web Services -> Generate Java Code from XML Schema using JAXB ...
4. Use Marshalling/Unmarshalling like this http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

Comment: The XML file may be much bigger and more complex than the section shown in the Q. Deriving an XML Schema from XML instances is risky. Not the preferred approach for a singular patch.